# Django 1.8 QuerySet: .extra syntax in Q object

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-1.8, django-q

I have several complex SQL Statements which are used to filter a django Queryset using .extra().

```
qs.extra(where=["my_jsonb_field-->'my_key'::text LIKE %s"], params=["myValue"])
```

Since these are queries on json fields, there is no possibility to get rid of these statements (at least not with django 1.8). Is it possible to use Q() objects with the .extra() syntax?

```
# Q has no .extra
Q().extra(...)

# Q has no .raw
Q().raw(...)
```

Comment: `extra()` and `raw()` work on `QuerySet` objects, not on `Q` objects. Just make a `QuerySet` first, (e.g. `qs = MyModel.objects.filter(q)` where `q` is your `Q()` object) then it'll work.

Comment: I want to use Q objects (or something similar) to run the statement as shown above, not do the query and then additional filtering. As I've stated, there are several of them - sometimes I'd need to chain them together using AND, sometimes using OR, which would be the perfect use case for Q objects IF they'd have .extra(), hence the question.

Comment: It’s not possible. But that shouldn’t be a problem: creating a `QuerySet` doesn’t “run the statement” (it’ll run only when you actually render the result or iterate through the elements) and since `QuerySet`s are sets, you can chain them to achieve OR or AND behavior using the `union()`, `intersection()` and `difference()` methods.

Comment: Sadly, `union()`, `intersection()` and `difference()` [were introduced with django 1.11](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#union).

Comment: Still, you nudged me into the right direction - I could get the raw SQL using `qs.query`, concatenate the strings manually with `raw_queries.join(' UNION ')` (or `INTERSECT` or `EXCEPT`) and putting the resulting string into a new QuerySet using `qs.raw()`!
Thanks!

Comment: Time to move to Django 1.11 :-) Note that Django 1.8 isn't supported anymore since april so there are security issues that haven't been fixed.